# how to do a character comparison in bash?

Tags: bash, compare

lets say I have a column showing `2/2` and I want to compare if the left side of the separator which in this case is `/` is matching with the right side? is there any way to achieve this in bash?

one possible method is using `IFS` but that requires to store the values in variables and then compare them using `IF` statement. I am trying to achieve this using a **oneliner** command.

Comment: You have to have _something_ stored in a variable. Some text, a filename, a column number, something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bash [expansion operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to extract each part and compare them directly.

```
var='2/2'
if [[ "${var%/*}" = "${var#*/}" ]]
then echo match
else echo no match
fi
```

`${var%/*}` removes the end of the variable matching the wildcard `/*`, so it  gets the first number. `${var#*/}` removes the beginning of the variable match the wildcard `*/`, so it gets the second number.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are seeking for the `bash` solution, how about an `awk` option:

```
col="2/2"
echo "$col" | awk -F/ '{print $1==$2 ? "match" : "no match"}'
```

- The `-F/` option sets the `awk`'s field separator to `/`.
- Then the input is split on `/` and the awk variable `$1` is assigned to
  the left side while `$2` is assigned to the right side.
- Now we can compare `$1` and `$2`.